# How to write and read to/from a QResource file in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile, qresource

It's strange, I add desired file into the resources via *Add Existing Files...*, the file is there. I run qmake ("Build->Run qmake") to make the file available.
The first issue: ***I can't write anything into the file from output terminal!*** But when I manually write into the file, the output terminal shows the change every time I run it. Second issue: it still says ***QIODevice::read: device not open*** !
Here's my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>

void wFile(QString Filename)
{ 
  QFile  nFile(Filename);
  QTextStream str(&nFile);
  qDebug() << "what do you want to write in the desired file: ";
  str.readLine();
  if (!nFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly  | QFile::Text))
  {
    qDebug() << "could not open the file";
    return;
  }
  nFile.flush(); 
  nFile.close();
 }

void read (QString Filename){
  QFile nFile(Filename);

  if(!nFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
  {
    qDebug() << "could not open file for reading";
    return;
  }
  QTextStream in(&nFile);
  QString nText = in.readAll();

  qDebug() << nText;
  nFile.close();
 }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 QString nFilename =":/MyFiles/DocumentArminV.txt";

 wFile(nFilename);
 read(nFilename);

 return a.exec();
}
```

And here's output terminal of the code:
[image: out put]

Comment: the items saved in qresource are **read-only**.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Even if it is short, this comment should be an answer. Because, as you stated, ressource files cannot be written (as they are compiled into the executable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files saved in a [qresource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) are **read-only** since they are part of the executable so you can not write or modify them.

[docs:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#compiled-in-resources)

[image]

*Currently, Qt always stores the data directly in the executable, even on Windows, macOS, and iOS, where the operating system provides native support for resources. ...*

Comment: Dear @eyllanesc Thanks a lot for your answer :) I mark the question as answered with your great answer. Though, I don't want to have two issues in one question, but if you would find out that the  answer this question is also just straight forward, just give me a hint please. Actually my main purpose is how to write a code to prompt user and write the desired text typed by that user into a specific file and then read it and show it in output terminal. I searched it but I haven't exactly found it yet. :(

Comment: @Armin change `":/MyFiles/DocumentArminV.txt"` to `"DocumentArminV.txt"`